# How to declare model class in react native and pass whole model class in second screen by use of react navigation

Tags: react-native

Is proper way to declare model class like java and how to pass this into second screen in react native?

```
export default class UserModel {

    stateName;
    username;
    email;
    mobile;
    gender;
    address;

    constructor() {}

    setStateName(stateName) {
        this.stateName = stateName;
    }
    setUserName(username) {
        this.username = username;
    }

    setEmail(email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    setMobile(mobile) {
        this.mobile = mobile;
    }

    setGender(gender) {
        this.gender = gender;
    }

    setAddress(address) {
        this.address = address;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Step 1: Make UserModel.js**

```
class UserModel {

    constructor() {
        stateName,
        username,
        email,
        mobile,
        gender,
        address;
    }

}
```

**Note: Do not Export it if you don't want to set globally.**

**Step 2 : Screen1.js - Set UserModel and pass from screen1.**

```
_handlePress = async () => {

        UserModel.username = "Vishal Patoliya"

        this.props.navigation.navigate('UserList',{userData: UserModel});

    }
```

**Step 3 : Receiving model class at another screen.**

```
render() {
        console.log(TAG, "render() Called.")

        const UserModel = this.props.navigation.getParam('userData');

        console.log("Username", UserModel.username)
}
```

**OutPut :**

```
01-16 17:30:32.085  4541  5638 I ReactNativeJS: 'Username', 'Vishal Patoliya'
```

Comment: When I reload the application  UserModel.username is undefined

Answer (score 3):

## Edit:

After some discussion, this was required answer:

```
this.props.navigation.navigate('UserList', { userModel: userModel });

this.props.getParam('userModel', /* optional default value */);
```

---

I assume this is your `UserModel.js`.
Now you are able to import the model like other components:

`import UserModel from './location/UserModel';`

But if you do it like this, you'd have to instanciate UserModel every time you import it.

If you'd like to prevent this, just instanciate a UserModel and export it inside the `UserModel.js` and import the instance anywhere.

Like this:

```
class UserModel {
    //...
}

export default new UserModel();
```

other way might be:

```
export class UserModel {
    //...
}

const GlobalUserModel = new UserModel(); 
export default GlobalUserModel;
```

to choose in other files what to import:

```
import { UserModel } from './location/UserModel'; //get new instance
```

or

```
import GlobalUserModel from './location/UserModel'; //get global instance
```

If imported via `{ UserModel }`, you have to instanciate first: `new UserModel()`

...or vice versa.

Comment: In react navigation can we pass this like other 
this.props.navigation.navigate('UserList', modelclass) ?

Comment: In this way might be memory will occupy more rather than pass into second screen , is there any way to do as i'm thinking ?

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand you correctly and why you want to pass it like that or don't want to declare a global instance. You should import it like other components. What do you expect from passing it with navigation? Btw I'm not sure if that even works.

Comment: If we forgot to clear this class instance than it may take more memory than we passing class from one screen to another.

Comment: Ok, in that case I'd recommend keeping your `UserModel.js` as is and using the normal import to instanciate a new UserModel on each screen you need it.

Comment: I think It is not a proper way to passing data.

Comment: In my code i'm facing problem to setting up data by using setter methods.

Comment: What are these problems? Do you have any error output? Do you want to keep data when navigating or do you want to clear it? You may update your question and be more clear ;)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/186777/discussion-between-vishal-patoliya--and-schogges).